# How to copy value from an array and assign it to another array in c?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

In python i will do like

```
grid = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']]
another_grid = [['a','a','a'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']]
another_grid[0][1] = grid[1][1]
```

Above code will change **'a'** to **'e'**. How to do this in c ?

Comment: `another_grid[0][1] = grid[1][1]; ` will work in C. It's the defining an array of arrays part that will be different.

Comment: the code i had written in python will change value for another_grid[0][1] which is 'a' to grid[1][1] which is 'e'

Comment: I want to write that code in c

Comment: @Nakib By the way, why didn't you google this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same, even the syntax is similar:

```
char grid[3][3] = { { 'a', 'b', 'c' }, { 'd', 'e', 'f' }, { 'g', 'h', 'i' } };
char another[3][3] = { { 'a', 'a', 'a' }, { 'd', 'e', 'f' }, { 'g', 'h', 'i' } };
another[0][1] = grid[1][1];
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I thought i will be different as like assigning array.